# Centos7 autocomplete path not work

Tags: linux, centos, autocomplete

In centos6, If I set

`testPath=/usr/local/bin`

and then

`ls $testPath/` press

it would be autocompleted as `ls /usr/local/bin`

but in Centos7, shown is `ls \$testPath/`

how to set this completion rule in centos7?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug introduced in newer versions of Bash.  The problem, and some workarounds, are discussed here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/41891/bash-auto-complete-for-environment-variables

The simplest solution is:
shopt -s direxpand

but it will change other behavior you might rely on.